# Raw query with rank over subquery / params not quoted

Tags: django, django-orm

## My Goal

I need PostgreSQL's rank() window function applied to an annotated queryset from Django's ORM. Django's sql query has to be a subquery in order to apply the window function and this is what I'm doing so far:

```py
queryset = Item.objects.annotate(…)

queryset_with_rank = Items.objects.raw("""
   select rank() over (order by points), *
     from (%(subquery)s)""", { 'subquery': queryset.query }
)
```

## The problem

Unfortunately, the query returned by `queryset.query` does not quote the parameters used for annotation correctly although the query itself is executed perfectly fine.

### Example of returned query

The query returned by `queryset_with_rank.query` or `queryset.query` returns the following

```
"participation"."category" = )
"participation"."category" = amateur)
```

which I rather expected to be

```
"participation"."category" = '')
"participation"."category" = 'amateur')
```

## Question

I noticed that the Django documentation states the following about `Query.__str__()`

> Parameter values won't necessarily be quoted correctly, since that is done by the database interface at execution time.

As long as I fix the quotation manually and pass it to Postgres myself, everything works as expected. Is there a way to receive the needed subquery with correct quotation? Or is there an alternative and better approach to applying a window function to a Django ORM queryset altoghether?

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/47371514/781312 *custom template in class basedo on Subquery

Answer (score 2):

As Django core developer [Aymeric Augustin said](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17741#comment:3), there's no way to get the exact query that is executed by the database backend beforehand.

I still managed to build the query the way I hoped to, although a bit cumbersome:

```py
# Obtain query and parameters separately
query, params = item_queryset.query.sql_with_params()

# Put additional quotes around string. I guess this is what 
# the database adapter does as well.
params = [
    '\'{}\''.format(p) 
    if isinstance(p, basestring) else p
    for p in params
]

# Cast list of parameters to tuple because I got 
# "not enough format characters" otherwise. Dunno why.
params = tuple(params)

participations = Item.objects.raw("""
    select *, 
           rank() over (order by points DESC) as rank
      from ({subquery}
    """.format(subquery=query.format(params)), []
)
```