# Ordering by sum of difference

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have a model that has one attribute with a list of floats:

```
values = ArrayField(models.FloatField(default=0), default=list, size=64, verbose_name=_('Values'))
```

Currently, I'm getting my entries and order them according to the sum of all diffs with another list:

```
def diff(l1, l2):
    return sum([abs(v1-v2) for v1, v2 in zip(l1, l2)])

list2 = [0.3, 0, 1, 0.5]
entries = Model.objects.all()
entries.sort(key=lambda t: diff(t.values, list2))
```

This works fast if my numer of entries is very slow small. But I'm afraid with a large number of entries, the comparison and sorting of all the entries will get slow since they have to be loaded from the database. Is there a way to make this more efficient?

Comment: Will you request all entries anyway or a very limited number of them (e.g. few with the smallest or largest `diff`?

Comment: More the latter by only showing the top N for example.

Answer (score 0):

best way is to write it yourself, right now you are iterating over a list over 4 times!

although this approach looks pretty but it's not good.

one thing that you can do is:

1. have a variable called `last_diff` and set it to `0`
2. iterate through all `entries`.
3. iterate though each `entry.values`
4. from i = 0 to the end of list, calculate `abs(entry.values[i]-list2[i])`
5. sum over these values in a variable called `new_diff`
6. if `new_diff > last_diff` break from inner loop and push the `entry` into its right place (it's called `Insertion Sort`, check it out!)

in this way, in average scenario, time complexity is much lower than what you are doing now!

and maybe you must be creative too. I'm gonna share some ideas, check them for yourself to make sure that they are fine.

assuming that:

1. `values` list elements are always positive floats.
2. `list2` is always the same for all `entries`.

then you may be able to say, the bigger the sum over the elements in `values`, the bigger the `diff` value is gonna be, no matter what are the elements in `list2`.

then you might be able to just forget about whole `diff` function. (test this!)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to makes this really go faster, is to move as much work as possible to the database, i.e. the calculations and the sorting. It wasn't easy, but with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543978/django-1-11-annotating-a-subquery-aggregate) I managed to actually write a query for that in almost pure Django:

```
class Unnest(models.Func):
    function = 'UNNEST'

class Abs(models.Func):
    function = 'ABS'

class SubquerySum(models.Subquery):
    template = '(SELECT sum(%(field)s) FROM (%(subquery)s) _sum)'    

x = [0.3, 0, 1, 0.5]
pairdiffs = Model.objects.filter(pk=models.OuterRef('pk')).annotate(
    pairdiff=Abs(Unnest('values')-Unnest(models.Value(x, ArrayField(models.FloatField())))), 
).values('pairdiff')
entries = Model.objects.all().annotate(
    diff=SubquerySum(pairdiffs, field='pairdiff')
).order_by('diff')
```

The `unnest` function turns each element of the `values` into a row. In this case it happens twice, but the two resulting columns are instantly subtracted and made positive. Still, there are as many rows per `pk` as there are `values`. These need to be summed, but that's not as easy as it sounds. The column can't be simply be aggregated. This was by far the most tricky part—even after fiddling with it for so long, I still don't quite understand why Postgres needs this indirection. Of the few options there are to make it work, I believe a subquery is the single one expressible in Django (and only as of 1.11).

Note that the above behaves exactly the same as with `zip`, i.e. the when one array is longer than the other, the remainder is ignored.

### Further improvements

While it will be a lot faster already when you don't have to retrieve all rows anymore and loop over them in Python, it doesn't change yet that it results in a full table scan. All rows will have to be processed, every single time. You can do better, though. Have a look into the `cube` extension. Use it to calculate the L<sub>1</sub> distance—at least, that seems what you're calculating—directly with the `<#>` operator. That will require the use of `RawSQL` or a custom `Expression`. Then add a GiST index on the SQL expression `cube("values")`, or directly on the field if you're able to change the type from `float[]` to `cube`. In case of the latter, you might have to implement your own `CubeField` too—I haven't found any package yet that provides it. In any case, with all that in place, top-N queries on the lowest distance will be fully indexed hence blazing fast.