# Sum of Subquery fields django

Tags: django, orm, django-aggregation, django-subquery

I have the following subquery:

```
Subquery(
         ContestTaskRelationship.objects.filter(
             contest=contest,
             solved=OuterRef('id')
         ).values('cost').all()
)
```

I need then to annotate my QuerySet with sum of `cost` values returned by each Subquery. How to do that? Wrapping the subquery in Sum returns only the first element of each subquery.

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42648980/641249

Comment: @neverwalkaloner, that does not work for me, as I have to sum all results of subquery, not annotate each with something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way without `Subquery`:

```
cost_sum=Sum(
            Case(
                When(
                    contest_task_relationship__contest=contest,
                    then='contest_task_relationship__cost'
                ),
                default=V(0),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            )
        )
```

Not an elegant way, but it works.