# Django QuerySet: additional field for counting value's occurence

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset, extra

I have a `QuerySet` object with 100 items, for each of them I need to know how many times a particular `contract_number` occurs in the `contract_number` field.

Example of expected output:

```
[{'contract_number': 123, 'contract_count': 2}, {'contract_number': 456, 'contract_count': 1} ...]
```

This means that value 123 occurs 2 times for the whole `contract_number` field.

Important thing: I cannot reduce the amount of items, so grouping won't work here.

The SQL equivalent for this would be an additional field `contract_count` as below:

```
 SELECT *,
 (SELECT count(contract_number) FROM table where t.contract_number = contract_number) as contract_count
FROM table as t
```

The question is how to do it with a Python object. After some research, I have found out that for more complex queries the [Queryset extra method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra) should be used. Below is one of my tries, but the result is not what I have expected

```
    queryset = Tracker.objects.extra(
    select={
        'contract_count': '''
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table
        WHERE contract_number = %s
        '''
    },select_params=(F('contract_number'),),)
```

My `models.py`:

```
class Tracker(models.Model):
    contract_number = models.IntegerField()
```

**EDIT:**
The solution to my problem was [Subquery()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

Answer (score 5):

You can use annotation like this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Tracker.objects.values('contract_number').annotate(contract_count=Count('contract_number')).order_by()
```

Comment: interesting, however instead of expected output, I am getting value: 1 for each item. For sure, there are contracts which are duplicated

Comment: @Supergator I suppose this is because of default ordering. Try to add `order_by()` as in my update. See detail here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by

Comment: Thanks, that's true, I had some ordering before in my query. Now, I am getting good counting values, the problem is that, it has reduced amount of items in the output - I have to keep original amount if items.

Comment: you have any idea, how to get counting values without reducing amount of items?

Comment: @Supergator try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42648980/641249

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

```
counttraker=Traker.objects.values('contract_number').annotate(Count('contract_number'))
subquery=counttraker.filter(contract_number=OuterRef('contract_number').values('contract_number__count')[:1]
traker=Traker.objects.annotate(count=Subquery(subquery))
```