# Using Subquery to annotate a Count

Tags: python, django, django-aggregation, django-annotate, django-subquery

Please help me I've been stuck on this for way too long :(

## What I want to do:

I have these two models:

```
class Specialization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=64)
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=128)
    # ...
    specialization = models.ForeignKey(Specialization)
```

I would like to annotate all specializations in a queryset with the number of doctors that have this specialization.

## My Solution so Far:

I went through a loop and I made a simple:  `Doctor.objects.filter(specialization=spec).count()` however this proved to be too slow and inefficient. 
The more I've read the more I realized that it would make sense to use a `SubQuery` here to filter the doctors for the `OuterRef` specialization. This is what I came up with:

```
doctors = Doctor.objects.all().filter(specialization=OuterRef("id")) \
    .values("specialization_id") \
    .order_by()
add_doctors_count = doctors.annotate(cnt=Count("specialization_id")).values("cnt")[:1]

spec_qs_with_counts = Specialization.objects.all().annotate(
    num_applicable_doctors=Subquery(add_doctors_count, output_field=IntegerField())
)
```

The output I get is just 1 for every speciality. The code just annotates every doctor object with its `specialization_id` and then annotates the count within that group, meaning it will be 1.

This doesn't make complete sense to me unfortunately. In my initial attempt I used an aggregate for the count, and while it works on its own it doesn't work as a `SubQuery`, I get this error:

`This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.`

I posted this question before and someone suggested doing `Specialization.objects.annotate(count=Count("doctor"))`

However this doesn't work because I need to count a specific queryset of Doctors.

## I've followed these links

However, I'm not getting the same result:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/
- https://medium.com/@hansonkd/the-dramatic-benefits-of-django-subqueries-and-annotations-4195e0dafb16
- [Django 1.11 Annotating a Subquery Aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543978/django-1-11-annotating-a-subquery-aggregate)

If you have any questions that would make this clearer please tell me.

Comment: I think you misunderatnd the semantics of `Count('doctor')`: it counts the *related* `doctor`s, so that means *per specialization*, you will get a (possibly) different number. It does *not* count *all* doctors, and annotates all specializations with that number.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Counting *all* `Doctor`s *per* `Specialization`

I think you make things overly complicated, probably because you think that `Count('doctor')` will count *every doctor* per specialization (regardless the specialization of that doctor). It does not, if you `Count` such related object, Django implicitly looks for *related* objects. In fact you can not `Count('unrelated_model')` at all, it is only through relations (reversed included) like a `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField`, etc. that you can query these, since otherwise these are not very *sensical*.

> I would like to annotate all specializations in a queryset with the number of doctors that have this specialization.

You can do this with a simple:

```
#  Counting all doctors per specialization (so not all doctors in general)

from django.db.models import Count

Specialization.objects.annotate(
    num_doctors=Count('doctor')
)
```

Now every `Specialization` object in *this* queryset will have an extra attribute `num_doctors` that is an integer (the number of doctors with that specialization).

You can also filter on the `Specialization`s in the same query (for example only obtain specializations that end on `'my'`). As long as you do not filter on the related `doctor`s set, the `Count` will work (see section below how to do this).

If you however filter on the related `doctor`s, then the related counts will filter out these doctors. Furthermore if you filter on *another* related object, then this will result in an extra `JOIN`, that will act as a *multiplier* for the `Count`s. In that case it might be better to use `num_doctors=Count('doctor', distinct=True)` instead. You can always use the `distinct=True` (regardless if you do extra `JOIN`s or not), but it will have a small performance impact.

The above works because `Count('doctor')` does not simply adds *all* doctors to the query, it makes a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the `doctor`s table, and thus checks that the `specialization_id` of that `Doctor` is exactly the one we are looking for. So the query Django will construct looks like:

```
SELECT specialization.*
       COUNT(doctor.id) AS num_doctors
FROM specialization
LEFT OUTER JOIN doctor ON doctor.specialization_id = specialization.id
GROUP BY specialization.id
```

Doing the same with a subquery will functionally get the same results, but if the Django ORM and the database management system do not find a way to optimize this, this can result in an expensive query, since for every specialization, it then can result in an extra subquery in the database.

## Counting *specific* `Doctor`s per `Specialization`

Say however you want to count *only* doctors that have a name that starts with *Joe*, then you can *add a filter* on the related `doctor`, like:

```
#  counting all Doctors with as name Joe per specialization

from django.db.models import Count

Specialization.objects.filter(
    doctor__name__startswith='Joe'  # sample filter
).annotate(
    num_doctors=Count('doctor')
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate it. I just tried this and initially thought this wasn't going to work, but it did! You're right I was overcomplicating this, I just thought the count for the doctors is going to count ALL the doctors for that Specialization, but the filter actually takes them out of the count. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The problem with `annotate` + `Count` is that (as I have discovered), Django generates a left outer join and then selects a `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.. which can be VERY SLOW because so many intermediate rows are generated in the result set

Comment: @little_birdie: yes, but the alternative of doing it one per element is slower, since then this yields a round trip per subquery. The idea of an annotate is that you do this if you need the count of *all* `Specialization`s, in that case this is, querywise more interesting than counting one per `Specialization`, since this is the famous *N+1* problem.

Comment: I'm not suggesting multiple round trips.  I'm suggesting that the query which django generates when you annotate(Count()) on a reverse join can be VERY slow, especially when you are doing multiple counts.. because it does an outer join to every table and then does a COUNT(DISTINCT).. this results in a huge number of rows for the server to sort through.  In my application, it took 5 seconds for postgres to execute django's query whereas my hand coded query which does `(SELECT COUNT(*) .. ) AS acount` executes in 34 milliseconds.

Comment: @little_birdie: but here we do not `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` note that there is no `Count(..., distinct=True)` in the ORM query, you can obtain  the query with `print(str(my_django_query.query))`, and I've tested in on both a MySQL and PostgreSQL, and both result, as expected in a `COUNT(doctor_id)` (as listed in the answer). Especially if there would be multiple aggregates involved, a JOIN will eventually outperform a subquery, since it performs multiple scans (source: https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/subqueries-and-joins-running-aggregates)

Comment: The `DISTINCT` is key here, since for a reasonable modern database system, the query plan will "collapse" the count to an accumulator, or it can even make use of the `MUL` index.

Answer (score 29):

## Problem

The problem is that Django adds `GROUP BY` as soon as it sees using an aggregate function.

## Solution

So you can just create your own aggregate function but so that Django thinks it is not aggregate. Just like this:

```
doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(
    specialization=OuterRef("id")
).order_by().annotate(
    count=Func(F('id'), function='Count')
).values('count')

spec_qs_with_counts = Specialization.objects.annotate(
    num_applicable_doctors=Subquery(doctors)
)
```

The more details on this method you can see in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69020732/10567223

Useful information can also be found in the docs about [using aggregates within a subquery expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#using-aggregates-within-a-subquery-expression) and [func expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions-1).

Comment: is there any difference in performance between both methods? i prefer this way as it avoids unwanted group by

Comment: It's more related to unperidictable query.
Without Func expression , It makes different result.
```Func(F('id'),function='Count')```
```Count('id')```
Those are totally diffrent.

I faced same problem.