# Count annotation adds unwanted group by statement for all fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-2.2

I want to generate the following query:

```sql
select id, (select count(*) from B where B.x = A.x) as c from A
```

Which should be simple enough with the [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) expression. Except I get a `group by` statement added to my count query which I can't get rid of:

```py
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

str(ContentType.objects.annotate(c=F('id')).values('c').query)
# completely fine query with annotated field
'SELECT "django_content_type"."id" AS "c" FROM "django_content_type"'

str(ContentType.objects.annotate(c=Count('*')).values('c').query)
# gets group by for every single field out of nowhere
'SELECT COUNT(*) AS "c" FROM "django_content_type" GROUP BY "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."app_label", "django_content_type"."model"'
```

Which makes the result be `[{'c': 1}, {'c': 1}, {'c': 1}, {'c': 1},...]` instead of `[{c:20}]`. But subqueries have to have only one row of result to be usable.

Since the query is supposed to be used in a subquery I can't use `.count()` or `.aggregate()` either since those evaluate instantly and complain about the usage of `OuterRef` expression.

Example with subquery:

```py
str(ContentType.objects.annotate(fields=Subquery(
    Field.objects.filter(model_id=OuterRef('pk')).annotate(c=Count('*')).values('c')
)).query)
```

Generates

```sql
SELECT "django_content_type"."id",
       "django_content_type"."app_label",
       "django_content_type"."model",
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS "c"
        FROM "meta_field" U0
        WHERE U0."model_id" = ("django_content_type"."id")
        GROUP BY U0."id", U0."model_id", U0."module", U0."name", U0."label", U0."widget", U0."visible", U0."readonly",
                 U0."desc", U0."type", U0."type_model_id", U0."type_meta_id", U0."is_type_meta", U0."multi",
                 U0."translatable", U0."conditions") AS "fields"
FROM "django_content_type"
```

Expected query:

```sql
SELECT "django_content_type"."id",
       "django_content_type"."app_label",
       "django_content_type"."model",
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS "c"
        FROM "meta_field" U0
        WHERE U0."model_id" = ("django_content_type"."id")) AS "fields"
FROM "django_content_type"
```

Update: (to add models from real app requested in comments):

```py
class Translation(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(MetaField, models.CASCADE)
    ref_id = models.IntegerField()
    # ... other fields

class Choice(models.Model):
    meta = models.ForeignKey(MetaField, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    # ... other fields
```

I need a query to get number of Translations available for each choice where `Translation.field_id` refers to `Choice.meta_id` and `Translation.ref_id` refers to `Choice.id`.

The reason there are no foreign keys is that not all meta fields are choice fields (e.g. text fields may also have translations). I could make a separate table for each translatable entity, but this setup should be easy to use with a count subquery that doesn't have a `group by` statement in it.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't do `ContentType.objects.annotate(c=Count('field')).values('id', 'c')` assuming `Field` has a fk to `ContentType`.

Comment: Subqueries need to only have one field selected. otherwise, the database won't know which field to extract for the outer query.

Comment: @dirkgroten Oh, you meant like not use a subquery at all, that won't work because the actual models don't have a simple relation. it's based on multiple fields. This was a simplified example to get the point about getting rid of `group by` across.

Comment: Then it would have helped to show the actual models.

Comment: @dirkgroten I thought the actual/expected query would be enough, given that I only need to remove part of the generated query while the rest of it is correct. But I added parts of the actual models. Thanks for your time.

Comment: `annotate` is the one creating the group query, because `annotate` always just considers one row at a time. `Field.objects.filter(model_id=pk).annotate(c=Count('*'))` never counts across multiple rows. It just does c=1 for every row

Comment: @dirkgroten Is there an alternative to annotate that would add aliases/custom selects without adding group by, or an alternative to aggregate that doesn't evaluate instantly so it could be used in a subquery expression?

Comment: `Choice.objects.annotate(c=Count('meta__translation', filter=Q(meta__translation__ref_id=F('id'))))`

Comment: maybe with the addition of `distinct=True` in the `Count()`

Comment: @dirkgroten Hmm, that would work in this specific case (although with 3 joins and a complicated group by clause (including dynamic columns) instead of a simple subquery) since they both have a relation to meta table, but I'm keeping the question open for the more generic answer. since aggregated subqueries are not that uncommon. (also I think a subquery would be faster?)

Comment: Another approach does not exist in the Django ORM, AFAIK. Use raw queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** Here's a query using subquery that should come close to what you want:

```
str(ContentType.objects.annotate(fields=Subquery(
    Field.objects.filter(model_id=OuterRef('pk')).values('model').annotate(c=Count('pk')).values('c')
)).query)
```

The only thing I did was adding the `values('model')` group_by clause which makes the `Count('pk')` actually work since it aggregates all rows into one.

It will return `null` instead of `0` when there are no related rows, which you can probably transform to 0 using a `Coalesce` function or a `Case ... When ... then`.

The exact query you want isn't possible with the Django ORM, although you can achieve the same result with

```
Choice.objects.annotate(c=Count(
    'meta__translation',
    distinct=True,
    filter=Q(meta__translation__ref_id=F('id'))
))
```

Alternatively look at the [django-sql-utils](https://github.com/martsberger/django-sql-utils) package, as also mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925437/django-subquery-with-aggregate).

Comment: Could you also provide an example of how to use the package you suggested? I installed it but it doesn't take a subquery expression just adding `count` to it. It takes a string, which is supposedly a relation/field on the model. How can I get it to count instances of another table with no relation to the current one?

Comment: As for your update, I figured that a `values()` before annotate can affect the `group by` clause, but that still doesn't give the same result (although very close). The main difference is null vs 0 in for fields with no matching rows. But that can be solved with a coalesce. I didn't think to use columns in the where clause for group by.

Comment: With sql-utils: `Choice.objects.annotate(c=SubqueryCount(‘meta__translation', filter=Q(meta__translation__ref_id=F('id'))))`

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a dirty hack, but after diving inside Django's ORM code, I found the following works wonderfully for me (I am trying to use your own example's subquery):

```
counting_subquery = Subquery( Field.objects
                                   .filter( model_id = OuterRef( 'pk' ) )
                                   .annotate( c = Count( '*' ) )
                                   .values('c') )

# Note: the next line fixes a bug in the Django ORM, where the subquery defined above
# triggers an unwanted group_by clause in the generated SQL which ruins the count operation.
counting_subquery.query.group_by = True

results = ContentType.objects
                     .annotate( fields_count = Subquery( counting_subquery ) )
                     ...
```

The key is setting `group_by` to `True`. That gets rid of the unwanted `group_by` clause in your SQL.

I am not happy about it, as it relies on Django's undocumented behaviour to work. But I can live with it; I am even less happy about the maintainability of using direct SQL in the subquery...