# Django multiple annotate slows down the query

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I have been debugging with `django debug_toolbar`, if I use more than one annotate in query then it takes a lot of time for Django to fetch the query results.

```
class Project_First(models.Model):
   project_first_results_M2M = models.ManyToManyField(Project_First_Results)

class Project_Second(models.Model):
   project_second_results_M2M = models.ManyToManyField(Project_Second_Results)

class Project(models.Model):
    project_first_M2M = models.ManyToManyField(Project_First)
    project_second_M2M = models.ManyToManyField(Project_Second)
```

- I m trying to count all the objects present in `project_first_results_M2M` of all the `project_first_M2M` objects.

ie, let's suppose, `project_first_M2M` has 3 objects of `Project_First` and I want to count all the total `project_first_results_M2M` objects present in all 3 of them.

```
Project.objects.all().annotate(first_res_count=Count('project_first_M2M__project_first_results_M2M',distinct=True))
```

- Above Query works fine and would take 80ms to fetch the results. But problem occurs when i try  to add an additional `annotate` to query.

```
Project.objects.all().annotate(first_res_count=Count('project_first_M2M__project_first_results_M2M',distinct=True)).annotate(second_res_count=Count('project_second_M2M__project_second_results_M2M',distinct=True))
```

- This would take almost 4000ms to fetch the results.

Both `project_second_M2M` and `project_first_M2M` contains the same fields and the same number of objects. I even tried in vice-versa condition to the above query and query slows down only when I add additional `annotate`.

- Is there any fast and alternate solution to achieve the same in much efficient way? maybe with raw sql queries.
- I want to count all the objects of `project_first_results_M2M` of all `project_first_M2M` objects within each `Project` object and similarly for `project_second_results_M2M`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can use [**`prefetch related`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
Project.objects.prefetch_related('project_first_M2M__project_first_results_M2M', 'project_second_M2M__project_second_results_M2M').annotate(first_res_count=Count('project_first_M2M__project_first_results_M2M',distinct=True)).annotate(second_res_count=Count('project_second_M2M__project_second_results_M2M',distinct=True))
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but using it along `prefetch_related` increases the query amount and time.

Comment: I tested with similar model structure as yours and had 25K entry per table, i did not face such issue. FYI i used mysql for testing.

Comment: Can you please paste the raw SQL query it made with  `.query`?

Answer (score 0):

> If you annotate on multiple different joins you generate a large amount of JOINs (in that example a total of four), which will indeed "blow up", the solution table. But it of course does not make any sense to perform such query. If you here perform a single nested JOIN, then it results in two JOINs, and you take all records that are yielded into account. - Williem

The solution proposed by `Matthew Schinckel` at [Django 1.11 Annotating a Subquery Aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543978/django-1-11-annotating-a-subquery-aggregate/47371514#47371514) using subquery trick for results in a much faster and optimized way.