# Django Nested ManyToManyField objects count query

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

- we have `Project` as main model, which contains 2 fields of M2M relationship.

```
class First(models.Model):
   first_results_M2M = models.ManyToManyField(First_Results)

class Second(models.Model):
   second_results_M2M = models.ManyToManyField(Second_Results)

class Project(models.Model):
    project_first_M2M = models.ManyToManyField(First)
    project_second_M2M = models.ManyToManyField(Second)
```

- I m trying to count all the objects present in `first_results_M2M` of all the `project_first_M2M` objects within each `Project` object.
- Here's the below example to count all the objects of `first_results_M2M` for `Project` object 1.

`total_first_all = First_Results.objects.filter(first__project__id=1).count()`

- I want to render the total count of `total_first_all` and `total_second_all` in the template.

```
Project_Query = Project.objects.all()
for each_proj in Project_Query:
  print(each_proj.total_first_all) ## should print the count the `first_resuls_M2M` for each project obj.
```

- Please let me know how to do achieve it in more effecient/fast way besides annotate.

`annotate.total_first_all=Count('project_first_M2M__first_results_M2M')`

Comment: You can `.annotate(...)`.

Comment: For the first time I tried with annotate then I realized that using annotate on multiple fields makes query extremely slow. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622503/django-multiple-annotate-slows-down-the-query

Comment: If you annotate on multiple *different* joins you generate a large amount of JOINs (in that example a total of four), which will indeed "blow up", the solution table. But it of course does not make any sense to perform such query. If you here perform a single nested JOIN, then it results in two JOINs, and you take all records that are yielded into account.

Comment: is there any way to perform a single nested JOIN from django ORM or have to do it with raw query?

Comment: you use a `Subquery`.

Answer (score 0):

You [**`.annotate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) your queryset, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

project_query = Project.objects.annotate(
    total_first_all=Count('project_first_M2M__first_results_M2M')
)

for project in project_query:
    print(project.total_first_all)
```

This will *not* make a query *per* `Project` object, but calculate the counts for *all* `Project`s in "bulk".

For multiple ones, you can make use of subqueries to reduce the amount of nested `JOIN`:

```
from django.db.models import Count, OuterRef, Subquery

project_query = Project.objects.annotate(
    total_first_all=Subquery(
        First_Results.objects.filter(first__project=OuterRef('pk')).values('first__project').values(cnt=Count('*')).order_by('first__project')
    ),
    total_second_all=Subquery(
        Second_Results.objects.filter(second__project=OuterRef('pk')).values('second__project').values(cnt=Count('*')).order_by('second__project')
    )
)
```

Comment: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: subquery must return only one column` over iterating `project_query` objects , I'm using `Postgresql` DB.

Comment: @ArbazzHussain: what if we use `.values(..)` with the `Count(..)` expression?

Comment: I'm sorry it throws out `AttributeError`, `AttributeError: 'Count' object has no attribute 'split'` , https://pastebin.com/raw/HDiHzC1N

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47371514/10372434 seems a neat solution to me , what do you think?

Comment: @ArbazzHussain: sorry, there was still a mistake.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, Above mentioned solution of `Matthew Schinckel` worked for me, Update the answer according to it so that I can accept it, Thanks