# Django ORM remove unwanted Group by when annotate multiple aggregate columns

Tags: sql, django, django-models, orm, django-orm

I want to create a query something like this in django ORM.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN myCondition THEN 1 ELSE NULL end) as numyear
FROM myTable
```

Following is the djang ORM query i have written

```
year_case = Case(When(added_on__year = today.year, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())

qs = (ProfaneContent.objects
                    .annotate(numyear=Count(year_case))
                    .values('numyear'))
```

This is the query which is generated by django orm.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN "analyzer_profanecontent"."added_on" BETWEEN 2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 AND 2020-12-31 23:59:59.999999+00:00 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS "numyear" FROM "analyzer_profanecontent" GROUP BY "analyzer_profanecontent"."id"
```

All other things are good, but django places a **GROUP BY** at the end leading to multiple rows and incorrect answer. I don't want that at all. Right now there is just one column but i will place more such columns.

**EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS**
I will be using the qs variable to get values of how my classifications have been made in the current year, month, week.

**UPDATE**
On the basis of comments and answers i am getting here let me clarify. I want to do this at the database end only (obviously using Django ORM and not RAW SQL). Its a simple sql query. Doing anything at Python's end will be inefficient since the data can be too large. Thats why i want the database to get me the sum of records based on the CASE condition.
I will be adding more such columns in the future so something like len() or .count will not work.

I just want to create the above mentioned query using Django ORM (without an automatically appended GROUP BY).

Comment: I am bit unclear on how you plan to use this qs variable

Comment: It's probably me, but .... isn't this just a fancy way of writing `ProfaneContent.objects.filter(added_on__year=today.year).count()`?

Comment: Yes it is but as i mentioned i am going to add other columns also. So count wont work there. Also these are the work arounds. I simply want a django ORM query.

Comment: Yes, but count as an annotation in this scenario is nonsense. As @hynekcer is demonstrating, this will only ever return one row. Annotate is used to add something to each row, not a group of rows.

Comment: Maybe the confusion is coming from your naming and use of count. Do you actually want to annotate each row with a boolean indicating it's the current year? Cause then just get rid of the Count and name it properly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When using aggregates in annotations, django needs to have some kind of grouping, if not it defaults to primary key. So, you need to use `.values()` before `.annotate()`. [Please see django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses).

But to completely remove group by you can use a static value and django is smart enough to remove it completely, so you get your result using ORM query like this:

```
year_case = Case(When(added_on__year = today.year, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())

qs = (ProfaneContent.objects
                    .annotate(dummy_group_by = Value(1))
                    .values('dummy_group_by')
                    .annotate(numyear=Count(year_case))
                    .values('numyear'))
```

Comment: Thank you a million. This was the thing i was looking for. Exactly at the point.

Comment: I give +1 because it works also, but I don't see any use case where an annotate() method with a dummy group_by could be better than an aggregate() method (see the answer below). Can you please explain how it could be better or why a method aggregate() exists if it can be replaced by annotate() with a dummy group?

Comment: @hynekcer Yeah, the use case is questionable. Typical XY problem.

Comment: from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/aggregation/ : 'Unlike aggregate(), annotate() is not a terminal clause. The output of the annotate() clause is a QuerySet; this QuerySet can be modified using any other QuerySet operation, including filter(), order_by(), or even additional calls to annotate().'

Comment: This is incredibly useful when the aggregate needs to be used in a subquery. It's a bit ridiculous that Django requires to annotate on a dummy field to remove the group by entirely, it's an important undocumented feature that warrants its own method IMO.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to summarize only to one row then you should to use an [.aggregate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.aggregate) method instead of annotate().

```py
result = ProfaneContent.objects.aggregate(
    numyear=Count(year_case),
    # ... more aggregated expressions are possible here
)
```

You get a simple dictionary of result columns:

```
>>> result
{'numyear': 7, ...}
```

The generated SQL query is without groups, exactly how required:

```sql
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN myCondition THEN 1 ELSE NULL end) as numyear
  -- and more possible aggregated expressions
FROM myTable
```

Comment: this will not return a queryset we may modify after definition but before running

Answer (score -1):

What about a list comprehension:

```
# get all the objects
profane = ProfaneContent.objects.all()
```

```
# Something like this 
len([pro for pro in profane if pro.numyear=today.year])
```

if the num years are equal it will add it to the list, so at the and you can check the len()

to get the count

Hopefully this is helpfull!

Comment: It will definitely give me the answer i want but that's not how it should be done. I would be better if we can do the same thing with SQL query only. Let database handle this stuff.

Comment: this would be better **ProfaneContent.objects.filter(numyear=today.year).count()**. I normally don't like writing SQL queries and advice not to use SQL queries unless you absolutely have to because the ORM can do everything you need.

Comment: I guess you got me wrong. By saying SQL i meant let the django's ORM handle the SQL query generation and Let the calculations happen at database end.

Also as i have mentioned i need to do the same thing for current month and week also. So if  i use 'filter' i would need to make 3 queries and it will lead to 3 different database hits. And that's awful.

Answer (score -2):

This is how I would write it in SQL.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN myCondition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as numyear
FROM myTable

SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN "analyzer_profanecontent"."added_on" 
                 BETWEEN 2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00 
                     AND 2020-12-31 23:59:59.999999+00:00 
             THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
         END) AS "numyear" 
FROM "analyzer_profanecontent" 
GROUP BY "analyzer_profanecontent"."id"
```

If you intend to use other items in the SELECT clause I would recommend using a group by as well which would look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN myCondition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as numyear
FROM myTable
GROUP BY SUM(CASE WHEN myCondition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: I know how to do it in SQL. Also as you mentioned the query, it has a group by its ID. And thats incorrect in my case. It will generate sum for each record and it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: I already mentioned that i want to remove that group by clause. And also i want to know how to do it with Django ORM not raw SQL.