# How to get count of more than one field from a table using Django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

here is my queryset

```
queryset = (PrathamTeamMembers.objects.
        select_related('state', 'district', 'block', 'personnel_type').
        filter(is_active=1).
        annotate(total_state=Count('state', distinct=True),
                 total_district=Count('district', distinct=True)))
```

I am expecting result similar to

```
{
 "total_state": 10
 "total_district": 60
}
```

But it is not aggregating instead it is grouping by table `PrathamTeamMembers` primary key. which I want to avoid. Since it is grouping on table primary key so my queryset giving result simlary to ..

```
[{
  "total_state": 1,
  "total_district": 1
},
{
  "total_state": 1,
  "total_district": 1
},
{
  "total_state": 1,
  "total_district": 1
}
]
```

Comment: If you want aggregations for the same table you need to use the `aggregate` method instead of `annotate`.

Comment: My bad. totally forgot to use aggregate method. It's working now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django ORM remove unwanted Group by when annotate multiple aggregate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63391064/django-orm-remove-unwanted-group-by-when-annotate-multiple-aggregate-columns)

Comment: Using `aggregate` instead of `annotate` fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this link for help.
GROUB BY ... COUNT/SUM Django ORM equivalent

https://riptutorial.com/django/example/30595/groub-by-----count-sum-django-orm-equivalent

We can perform a GROUP BY ... COUNT or a GROUP BY ... SUM SQL equivalent queries on Django ORM, with the use of annotate(), values(), order_by() and the django.db.models's Count and Sum methods respectfully: