# Django Annotation Count with Subquery & OuterRef

Tags: django, django-annotate, django-aggregation, django-subquery

I'm trying to create a high score statistic table/list for a quiz, where the table/list is supposed to be showing the percentage of (or total) correct guesses on a person which was to be guessed on. To elaborate further, these are the models which are used.

The Quiz model:

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        through="Participant",
        through_fields=("quiz", "correct_user"),
        blank=True,
        related_name="related_quiz",
    )
    fake_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="quiz_fakes")
    user_quizzed = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="user_taking_quiz", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True
    )
    time_started = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    time_end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    final_score = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
```

This model does also have some properties; I deem them to be unrelated to the problem at hand.

The Participant model:

```
class Participant(models.Model):  # QuizAnswer FK -> QUIZ
    guessed_user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="clicked_in_quiz", null=True
    )
    correct_user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="solution_in_quiz", null=True
    )
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(
        Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="participants_in_quiz"
    )

    @property
    def correct(self):
        return self.guessed_user == self.correct_user
```

To iterate through what I am trying to do, I'll try to explain how I'm thinking this should work:

1. For a `User` in `User.objects.all()`, find all `participant` objects where the `user.id` equals `correct_user`(from `participant` model)
2. For each `participant`object, evaluate if `correct_user`==`guessed_user`
3. Sum each `participant` object where the above comparison is `True` for the `User`, represented by a field `sum_of_correct_guesses`
4. Return a queryset including all users with parameters [`User`, `sum_of_correct_guesses`]

^Now ideally this should be `percentage_of_correct_guesses`, but that is an afterthought which should be easy enough to change by doing `sum_of_correct_guesses` / sum n times of that person being a guess.

Now I've even made some pseudocode for a single person to illustrate to myself roughly how it should work using python arithmetics

```
# PYTHON PSEUDO QUERY ---------------------
person = get_object_or_404(User, pk=3)  # Example-person
y = Participant.objects.filter(
    correct_user=person
)  # Find participant-objects where person is used as guess
y_corr = []  # empty list to act as "queryset" in for-loop

for el in y:  # for each participant object
    if el.correct:  # if correct_user == guessed_user
        y_corr.append(el)  # add to queryset
y_percentage_corr = len(y_corr) / len(y)  # do arithmetic division
print("Percentage correct: ", y_percentage_corr)  # debug-display
# ---------------------------------------------
```

What I've tried (with no success so far), is to use an ExtensionWrapper with `Count()` and `Q` object:

```
percentage_correct_guesses = ExpressionWrapper(
Count("pk", filter=Q(clicked_in_quiz=F("id")), distinct=True)
/ Count("solution_in_quiz"),
output_field=fields.DecimalField())

all_users = (
User.objects.all().annotate(score=percentage_correct_guesses).order_by("score"))
```

Any help or directions to resources on how to do this is greatly appreciated :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer while looking around for related problems:
[Django 1.11 Annotating a Subquery Aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543978/django-1-11-annotating-a-subquery-aggregate)

What I've done is:

- Create a filter with an `OuterRef()` which points to a `User` and checks if `User`is the same as `correct_person` and also a comparison between `guessed_person` and `correct_person`, outputs a value `correct_user` in a queryset for all elements which the filter accepts.
- Do an annotated count for how many occurrences there are of a `correct_user` in the filtered queryset.
- Annotate `User` based on the annotated-count, this is the annotation that really drives the whole operation. Notice how `OuterRef()` and `Subquery` are used to tell the filter which user is supposed to be `correct_user`.

Below is the code snippet which I made it work with, it looks very similar to the answer-post in the above linked question:

```
from django.db.models import Count, OuterRef, Subquery, F, Q

crit1 = Q(correct_user=OuterRef('pk'))
crit2 = Q(correct_user=F('guessed_user'))
compare_participants = Participant.objects.filter(crit1 & crit2).order_by().values('correct_user')
count_occurrences = compare_participants.annotate(c=Count('*')).values('c')
most_correctly_guessed_on = (
    User.objects.annotate(correct_clicks=Subquery(count_occurrences))
    .values('first_name', 'correct_clicks')
    .order_by('-correct_clicks')
)
return most_correctly_guessed_on
```

This works wonderfully, thanks to [Oli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12870/oli).