# Annotating in django using a field from another model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, django-annotate

I'm trying to calculate a field that it's a sum agregation when two of other fields are the same. The problem is that one of this fields is from the same model as the sum field, but the other one is from another model.

models.py:

```
class Node(model.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Text'))
    perimeter_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('Perimeter_ID'))
    pos_x = models.FloatField(verbose_name=_('Position X'))
    pos_y = models.FloatField(verbose_name=_('Position Y'))
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['pk']


class Routes(models.Model):
    from_id = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_('From'), related_name='transport_from')
    to_id = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=_('To'), related_name='transport_to')
    n_box = models.FloatField(verbose_name=_('Number of boxes'))
    day = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=_('day'))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['from_id__id', 'to_id__id']
```

And in my views, I'm first filtering by day as the request will be something like `filter/?day=20220103` and then I want to know the sum of boxes when `from_id` and `perimeter_id` are the same (the `perimeter_id` of the node corresponding to `to_id`). So, I need somehow to make the relation between, the `to_id` node and its `perimeter_id`.

views.py:

```
class sumByPerimeterListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Routes.objects.all()
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = {
        'day': ["in", "exact"],
    }
    def get(self, request, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        filter_queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        values = filter_queryset.values('from_id')\ # TODO: INCLUDE  perimeter_id OF to_id
            .annotate(n_box=Sum('n_box'))
        return Response(values)
```

I've been reading about `subquery` and `OuterRef` in Django, also in the following link: [Django 1.11 Annotating a Subquery Aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543978/django-1-11-annotating-a-subquery-aggregate). But these examples are not valid for me as I don't need to annotate the field `perimeter_id`. I need to agrupate by `from_id` (model Routes) and `perimeter_id` (model Node) and annotate by `n_box`.

Comment: I understand that `values = filter_queryset.values('from_id', 'to_id__perimeter_ID')       .annotate(n_box=Sum('n_box'))` should do it, but it's not doing the agrupation.

Answer (score 0):

To get a conditioned annotation, try using the `case when` statement inside the annotation:

Below is an example  of it

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, IntegerField
Article.objects.annotate(
    numviews=Count(Case(
        When(readership__what_time__lt=treshold, then=1),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    ))
)
```

In your case you have to change the below line as follows:

```
values = filter_queryset.annotate(n_box=Sum(When(Case (from_id=from_id.perimeter_ID, then=n_box), n_box=DecimalField())
```

Try something similar using `when`, `case`, and `then`.

I hope it will solve your conditioning issues.

Also, have a look at F expressions. They are very useful when it comes to conditioning.