# How can I do this complex Django queryset correctly?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Let's say I have these three models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Book(models.Model):
   author = models.ForeignKey(
        Author,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
   name = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class Store(models.Model):
   books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

I don't know the author of some books. In these cases, the author is null.

When I query Store, I would like to know how many books each store has and sort them. So my queryset is something like this:

```
Store.objects.all().annotate(books_count=Count('books')).order_by('-books_count')
```

Now, what if I want to count only the books that have an author?

I tried this queryset, but it is clearly not correct:

```
filter = Q(books__author__isnull=False)
Store.objects.annotate(books_count=Count(filter)).all().order_by('-books_count')
```

Does anyone know the correct way to do this query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django 1.11 Annotating a Subquery Aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543978/django-1-11-annotating-a-subquery-aggregate)

Comment: Filter books with `OuterRef` and author predicate, then annotate stores with count based on this `Subquery`.

Comment: Can you post the error you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe following query is what you are looking for.

```
books_count = (
    Book.objects.filter(
        store=OuterRef("pk"),
        author__isnull=False,
    )
    .annotate(count=Func(F("id"), function="COUNT"))
    .values("count")
)
Store.objects.annotate(count=Subquery(books_count)).order_by("-count")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go the other way around:

```
Book.objects.filter(author__isnull=False).values('store_set').annotate(count=Count('store_set')).order_by('-count')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a bit of a wild guess, but im thinking your usage of a `Q` object might be incorrect inside of the`Count`.

`Count` is expecting an expression like object, this could be a string, F, OuterRef, SubQuery and so on.

```
Store.objects.filter(filter).annotate(
     books_count=Count("books")
).order_by('-books_count')
```

I think this is what you're after.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I understand that using Q is not correct. I need something a bit different. Your query will filter the stores, but I want all of them. What I need is to filter the books, which are counted.
I am reading the documentation on query expressions, but I still didn't find the right way to implement this query.